# Tax lien investing: Possible in Canada?

Tags: investing, canada, real-estate, risk

I was just reading on the tax lien investing process and how it works in the United States.

I was wondering if it happens in other countries. In specific, I would like to know if it happens in Canada and allows for citizens to invest money in that fashion or is there an similar/different process that occurs in Canada.

Answer (score 3):

Canada does not have tax lien certificates. Instead, they do tax deed sales.  Because the process is much further along, often involving local sheriffs, it is much closer to a U.S. foreclosure sale/auction process than a tax lien as you are likely thinking.  The laws and processes vary by province as well, so you'll want to contact the provincial government tax offices to get the details.